# i want to place a div nearer to a text box in an html form

Tags: html, css

can anyone help me?
I need to place a div after a textbox in a html form.
ie.label,textbox,and new div is in same line

please see my html code .i didn't add div code yet.

please can any one help me to add a div in same line without any modification to this codes.
because i made several css codes for aligning this labels and text boxes

```
<form action="operates/signup.php" method="post" name="signupform" id="signupform">

      <label id="fnamelabel" for="fnam">First Name :</label>
      <input type="text" name="fnam" id="fnam" tabindex="1" />

    <p>
      <label id="lnamelabel"  for="lnam">Last Name :</label>
      <input type="text" name="lnam" id="lnam" tabindex="2" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label id="yemail" for="email">Your Email :</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" tabindex="3" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label id="reemail" for="remail">Re-enter Email :</label>
      <input type="text" name="remail" id="remail" tabindex="4" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label id="npass" for="password">New Password :</label>
      <input type="text" name="password" id="password" tabindex="5" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label id="mskill" for="bskill">Main Skill :</label>
      <select name="bskill" id="bskill" tabindex="6">
      </select>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="checkbox" name="termsanc" id="termsanc" tabindex="6" />
      <label id="terms" for="termsanc">I agreed the <a href="index.html">Terms and Conditions</a></label>
    </p>
    <div id="signupbutton" onclick="document.forms.signupform.submit()"></div>
  </form>
```

Thank you

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. `form`, `p` and `div` are not allowed inside of a `table` element. Or `tr` and `td` elements are not allowed outside of one.

Comment: You are also using a `<div>` to mimic a button. This can cause accessibility and usability issues.

Comment: @Truth can you provide a source?  I have no trouble believing that's true, but I didn't find a reference to it in the spec.

Comment: @RyanB i didn't find any issue because this type of codings is used in elance website

Comment: @Truth all of those are allowed in tables provided that they're inside the `td` element

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt: Not directly as presented in this HTML code.

Comment: @Sam, a `<div>` cannot gain focus by default. Right there you are discriminating against people who use the keyboard. So your options to overcome your accessibility issues are `<div id="..." onclick="..." tabindex="-1" role="button">` and ensuring that the click works. OR `<input type="submit" id=".." value='...">`

Comment: @Truth ah, i didn't see the original one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can style the div as inline, but you should rather use a span.

Comment: can you give me a example for this...example must relate to above codes

Comment: the last line with inline style:
<div id="signupbutton" onclick="document.forms.signupform.submit()" style="display:inline;">sign button</div> <div style="display:inline;">same line div</div>.
But why not use a span instead of the 'same line div'

Answer (score 0):

```
<label id="fnamelabel" for="fnam" style = "display:inline">First Name :</label>
<input type="text" name="fnam" id="fnam" tabindex="1" style = "display:inline" />
<div id="newDiv" style = "display:inline"></div>
```

normally I wouldn't use in-line CSS like that, but as you didn't post the css i felt it'd be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's work on that markup!

```
<form action="operates/signup.php" method="post" name="signup_form">
    <label>First Name:
        <input name="first_name"></label>
    <label>Last Name:
        <input name="last_name"></label>
    <label>Your Email:
        <input type="email" name="email"></label>
    <label>Please Reenter Your Email:
        <input type="email" name="validate_email"></label>
    <label>New Password:
        <input type="password" name="password"></label>
    <label>Main Skill:
        <input name="main_skill"></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="terms_and_conditions">I agreed the <a href="index.html">Terms and Conditions</a></label>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<style type="text/css">
    form {
        display: block;
        width: 400px;
    }
    label {
        display: block;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 5px;
    }
    form label input {
        float: right;
    }
    input[type=checkbox] {
        float: none;
    }
</style>
```

There, now doesn't that look much better?

---

As for the original question, don't use a `div`, `div` is a **completely-unsemantic *block-level* element**. If you want an inline element (i.e. to show on the same line), use a `span`, which is a **completely-unsemantic *inline-level* element**.